# Parse data as time with function (Python)

Tags: python-3.6, jupyter

Getting the following error following an execution of the following code. Using Py3 on Jupyter.

```
def parse_date(date):
    if date == '':
        return None
    else:
        return dt.strptime(str(date, '%d/%m/%y').date()`

raw_data_1.Date = raw_data_1.Date.apply(parse_date)    
raw_data_2.Date = raw_data_2.Date.apply(parse_date) 



File "<ipython-input-16-262d54bff117>", line 9
    raw_data_1.Date = raw_data_1.Date.apply(parse_date)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: When posting code, be sure to use the backtick ( ` ) or `CTRL+K` so that it is actually readable.

Comment: Count the parentheses in your `dt.strptime` line.  Voting to close as typo.

Comment: behind `date()` there is an extra backtick(`) and also you missed a parenthesis.